# TASM program freezes after mov

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm, dosbox

I have an issue with my program. Everything works well except mov bx, 0 freezes the program. Also, dosbox gives error:

> Illegal read from de74395c, CS:IP 1a2: 140

I have no clue why it does this. I tried loadfix command, but it didn't help. Any advice? Thank you.

```
LOCALS @@
.386
.model small

.stack 1000h

.code
start:        

check_args:
  call get_argc

exit:
  mov ah, 4Ch
  int 21h

proc get_argc
  mov bx, 0         
  jmp exit
  mov di, 80h       
  mov cx, es:[di]  

  @@L1:
    inc di         
    mov al, es:[di] 
    cmp al, 20h     
    je @@L1        
    cmp al, 09h    
    je @@L1        
    cmp al, 0Dh     
    je @@done       

    inc bx         

  @@L2:
    inc di
    mov al, es:[di]
    cmp al, 20h
    je @@L1
    cmp al, 09h
    je @@L1
    cmp al, 0Dh
    je @@done
        jmp @@L2

    @@done:
        mov ax, bx
        ret
endp

end start
```

Comment: _"`mov bx, 0` freezes the program"_. That seems very unlikely, unless maybe if the instruction itself was located at an illegal address. Could you post some of the relevant parts of your code?

Comment: There is no way to tell without source code.

Comment: Updated. That's not whole code, but other side doesn't get executed in any way, so i removed it for you.

Comment: If you'll comment your code, I'll look at it.

Comment: restarting pc helped. :?

Answer (score 0):

Your `.386` is at the wrong place. It must be set (if at all) **after** the `.model small` directive.